# Using the RxJS ForkJoin operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, fork-join

How to rewrite this code with the RxJS ForkJoin operator?

```js
this.arrItems.forEach((item) => {
    this.objectService.update(item).subscribe();
});

//objectFacade
public update(itemObject: ItemObject): Observable<ItemObject> {
    let observable = this.objectService.update(this.map(itemObject));
    return observable
        .flatMap(objective => this.getItemObject(itemObject.id))
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
}

//objectService
public update(item: T): Observable < T > {
    return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + item.id, item)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

my sample:

```js
const streams = this.arrItems.map(item =>
    this.objectService.update(item)
);
forkJoin(...streams).subscribe();
```

but, I get error:

> Argument of type 'void[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SubscribableOrPromise'.
>   Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike'.
>   Property 'then' is missing in type 'void[]'.`

Comment: is it a typo?? `let observable;
    this.objectService.update(this.map(itemObject));` should be `let observable=
    this.objectService.update(this.map(itemObject));`

Comment: @joyBlanks, it's typo. thank you

Comment: can you try `forkJoin(streams)` instead of `forkJoin(...streams)`??

Comment: @joyBlanks I have tried. the error is the same. I'm using rxjs version 5.5

Comment: i think that map is non-blockable code, try using the for loop or forEach and push into the streams array.

Comment: Can you show what `handleError` does? it looks like the problem could be there. The way you use `forkJoin` seems fine to me.